# How to make pyramid with sum of the string with python

Tags: python, sum

for example of '`31415926535897`', should be applying the rule of `1 2 2 3 3 3` which can be shown like `(3) (1 + 4) (1 + 5) (9 + 2 + 6) (5 + 3 + 5)  (8 + 9 + 7)` which results,

```
3
5 6
17 13 24
```

in which i made my code for pyramid is,

```
for i in range(rows):
   for j in range(i + 1):
       print(i, end=" ")
   print("\r")
```

but i can't get it how to apply the sum of the `1 2 2 3 3 3` structure. Should i use `sum(x for x in range())` or what should i do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this solution may work well as far as the `string` provided accomplishes with the requirements to apply the pyramid sum completely.

```
string = "31415926535234"

structure = 1
pos = 0
result = ""

while not pos==len(string):
    for i in range(structure):
        ans = 0
        for j in range(structure):
            ans += int(string[pos+j])
        result += str(ans)+" "
        pos = pos+structure
    structure += 1
    result += "\n"

print(result)
```

If you input `31415926535234` it works well, but if you delete the last digit, it will not work because you wouldn't be able to complete the sum of 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itertools.groupby`, it transforms `[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]` into `{1:[1], 2:[2,2], 3:[3,3,3]}`, then use to slice the input for sum

```
from itertools import groupby

s = '31415926535897'
rules = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]

for value, count in groupby(rules):
    for j in range(len(list(count))):
        group = sum(map(int, s[:value]))
        print(group, end=" ")
        s = s[value:]
    print()
```

Comment: it could be really hard code for me, but i will try my best to understand the code. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Since row tells you the number of digits to sum and the number of times you'd do that (e.g. in row 2  we take the sum of 2 digits and we do that twice) you could do the ff:

1. Identify the appropriate substring; increment pos by row. Also the size of substring can be also determined by the row number.

   stri[pos: pos+row]
2. Take the sum by first converting each char to int

   [int(ch) for ch in stri[pos: pos+row]]

So, we get this

```
stri = '31415926535897'
pos = 0
row = 1
while pos < len(stri):
  for i in range(row):
    print(sum([int(ch) for ch in stri[pos: pos+row]]), end=' ')
    pos += row
  row += 1
  print()
```